# Split vector by location

Tags: r

If there is a vector `x` with

```
length(x)
# 100
```

And there is a vector `a`, which denotes the leading index of subvector of x:

```
a
# 1, 5, 23, 79
```

Then I want to split `x` according to `a` as follow:

```
list(x[1:4], x[5:22], x[23:78], x[79:100])
```

Is there a quick way to do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the previous answers rely on making lists/vectors for splitting that are the same length as the original `x` vector. This might be inefficient in the instance of a very long vector and can be avoided:

```
Map(function(i,j) x[i:j], a, cumsum(diff(c(a, length(x)+1))))
```

Comment: +1 cool -- definitely a speedup even for a 100-element vector. I got an even better speedup by replacing the last argument with `c(a[-1], length(x))`.

Comment: Correction -- `c(a[-1]-1, length(x))` is the correct replacement for the last argument.

Answer (score 4):

This is a one-liner with `rep` and `split`:

```
split(x, rep(seq(a), diff(c(a, length(x)+1))))
```

`seq(a)` returns the numbers 1 through 4, and `rep` repeats them the proper number of times based on `a` (extracted using the `diff` function). Finally, `split` breaks up an object passed as the first parameter using categories passed as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(seq(a),function(i) x[a[i]:c(a[-1]-1,length(x))[i]])
```

Explanation of the code:

```
seq(a) #returns a index vector of length 4  

as.list(seq(a))
```

or

```
lapply(seq(a),function(i) i) #returns a list with the index elements (1:4)

lapply(seq(a),function(i) a[i])#returns the list with corresponding values of `a`
lapply(seq(a),function(i) c(a[-1]-1, length(x))[i]) #returns list with end points
```

Joining the above two lines of code:

```
lapply(seq(a),function(i) a[i]:c(a[-1]-1, length(x))[i]) # sequence of start:end points

lapply(seq(a),function(i) x[a[i]:c(a[-1]-1, length(x))[i]]) #returns the values of x between start:end index
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct the list of index vectors, then `lapply()`:

```
vec <- mapply(seq,a,length=diff(c(a,101)))
lapply(vec,function(v) x[v])
```